# permalink that goes straight to a div within a post

Tags: php, echo, permalinks

I was wondering what is the php code to go directly to a div on single post on a  wordpress page (comments)

For example.  The link to go to the comments section of a particular post would be http://badsentinel.com/2013/05/06/afternoon-awesomeness-41-photos-2/#idc-container  (I am using Intense Debate comment plugin)  But I dont want to manually type the a href on every single post.

I would like to know if someone can help me out with the below code. Im sure it is something similar..

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->#idc-container); ?> Jump to Comments </a>
```

Thanks in advance
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the comments div anchor has a constant identifier you don't need any PHP to refer to it. Just add it after the dynamic post link:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink({{id}}); ?>/#idc-container" /> Jump to Comments </a>
```

replace `{{id}}` with the post ID

That being said, if you are using an ***internal*** anchor tag, you don't even need the permalink:

```
<a href="#idc-container" /> Jump to Comments </a>
```

would add the anchor to the existing URL